# IONIC CORDOVA Error APK or App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast with intent filter, but without 'android:exported'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

It's the same error that everyone else has reported, but since this app uses Ionic, everytime after I have added the "android:export" property and then I run `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` there are new properties being added to AndroidManifest...

These are the properties that need the "android:export":

> android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
> android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent"
> android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
> android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I added the cordova-custom-config plugin to be able to change the AndroidManifest.xml through Config.xml file. Its quite simple, just add the plugin, than I added this code inside Config.xml:

```
<platform name="android">
        <custom-config-file parent="./application" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
          <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
          </activity>
          <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent">
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            </intent-filter>
          </receiver>
          <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.MyFirebaseMessagingService" android:stopWithTask="false">
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
          </service>
          <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
            </intent-filter>
          </receiver>
        </custom-config-file>
</platform>
```

Then ionic cordova build ... And voilá!